# Find host from ItemContainerGenerator.itemChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, itemcontainergenerator

I'm working on C# 4.0, WPF. I have three ListView, and all three controls have the same ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged" event handler. So my problem is that I want to find the host `ListView` from within the event handler.

```
lst1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged);

lst2.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged);

lst3.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged);


void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(
    object sender,
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Find ListView instance.
        // **REAL Problem**
        // ListViewItem's Visible property has been set based on the deletion
        // button click, so at one place i have to get the count of rows which
        // are visible and proceed with related buttons enable/disable operation.
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use lambdas as event handlers so that you can forward the `ListView` instance to your "real" handler.

```
lst1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += 
    (o, e) => this.ListViewGeneratorItemsChanged(o, e, lst1);

lst2.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += 
    (o, e) => this.ListViewGeneratorItemsChanged(o, e, lst2);

lst3.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += 
    (o, e) => this.ListViewGeneratorItemsChanged(o, e, lst3);

void ListViewGeneratorItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e, ListView listView)
{
    // We have the ListView and also the ItemContainerGenerator (in sender)
}
```

Comment: I may get only ItemContainerGenerator, i need to get any one of list view itself. i.e lst1 or lst2 or lst3. ItemContainerGenerator holds host as a private member, so i couldn't access the list it belongs to.

Comment: @Mohanavel: Updated my answer, check it out. I had not understood the question correctly.